# Jquery autocomplete is not a function after added all jquery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

Hello everyone I am using jquery autocomplete function to fill text box auto completely here is my code

```
$("#txtcountry").autocomplete({

            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "home/GetCountry",
                    data: "{'username':'" + document.getElementById('txtSearch').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("Error");
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

and order of my Jquery plugins is

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

But it stills showing error in console that **$(...).autocomplete** is not a function
please suggest me where I am going wrong
thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the console and verify that JQuery and jquery-ui is loaded properly?

Comment: yes it is loading properly

Comment: `~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js` seems like it would be unlikely to work... are you sure you're not getting a 404 for that? Does other code that uses jQuery on the page work?

Comment: no i am not getting 404 on that

Comment: Are you maybe including any other jquery or jquery-ui versions somewhere else? This could cause a conflict.

Comment: Where on the page is your JavaScript code? Is there any chance it's running before the `script` tags that pull in jQuery / jQuery UI?

Comment: it is on bottom of a page under script section

Comment: Can you create fiddle of this to simulate?

Comment: I'd suggest setting up a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) to try to reproduce the problem. Making a reasonable assumption about what's in `~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js`, the code you've shared works. We'll need a way to reproduce the problem to figure out what's causing it.

Answer (score -3):

I have just replaced jQuery library import with one which I have because in your question, it is relative import.

Below code working fine in my case with fix provided tags for autocomplete but it is not throwing error on autocomplete function.

```
    <script src="jquery-1.x-git.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var availableTags = [
                "Apple",
                "Pineapple",
                "Java",
                "ASP",
                "PHP"
            ];
            $("#txtcountry").autocomplete({
                source: availableTags
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 You can try by just replacing code with mine, i think there must be problem with your import otherwise it should work.

Comment: May i know reason for downvote or who has downvoted it ?

Comment: Can you try replacing only code of autocomplete with your code to check whether error is from that code segment ? or it would be better if you can create fiddle as @smarx said.

Comment: from where i get jquery-1.x-git.min.js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148500/discussion-between-gaurav-0093-and-technocrat).